# Strange issue Doctrine/Symfony request

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've some trouble with an simple request, who have very strange behavior:

```
$villes = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('v')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();

foreach ($villes as $value) {
    $v = $this->_em->createQuery('
        SELECT v
        FROM Btp\UserProBundle\Entity\Ville v
        WHERE GEO(v.lat = :latitude, v.lng = :longitude) <= :r
        ')
    ->setParameter('latitude', $lat)
    ->setParameter('longitude', $lng)
    ->setParameter('r', $value->getRayon()) // 20
    ->getResult();
    }
```

Problem is, when I hardcode "20" in setParam for 'r', the query return the good answer.
But when I pass my variable  $value->getRayon() (who is equal two 20 too), the request found nothing. I don't understand how it's possible...

EDIT: Generated SQL by the query:

```
string(341) "
    SELECT v0_.id AS id0, v0_.nom AS nom1, v0_.lat AS lat2, v0_.lng AS lng3, v0_.rayon AS rayon4, v0_.slug AS slug5, v0_.nb_pro AS nb_pro6
    FROM villes v0_ 
    WHERE ((ACOS(SIN(? * PI() / 180) * SIN(v0_.lat * PI() / 180) + COS(? * PI() / 180) * COS(v0_.lat * PI() / 180) * COS((? - v0_.lng) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344) <= ?
"
```

EDIT2: Okay, So I find the query with the toolbar, and all of you are right, the placeholder have good value:

```
SELECT 
v0_.id AS id0, 
v0_.nom AS nom1, 
v0_.lat AS lat2, 
v0_.lng AS lng3, 
v0_.rayon AS rayon4, 
v0_.slug AS slug5, 
v0_.nb_pro AS nb_pro6 
FROM 
villes v0_ 
WHERE 
(
(
  ACOS(
    SIN(
      ? * PI() / 180
    ) * SIN(
      v0_.lat * PI() / 180
    ) + COS(
      ? * PI() / 180
    ) * COS(
      v0_.lat * PI() / 180
    ) * COS(
      (? - v0_.lng) * PI() / 180
    )
  ) * 180 / PI()
 ) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344
) <= ?
Parameters: [44.8769806, 44.8769806, -0.5519386, 20]
```

But any result is found!!! When I write 20 in hardcore that work! I don't understand anything what happend...

Comment: Are you sure that `getRayon()` returns 20? Did you check it manually? `createQuery()` has `getSQL()` method - get final query instead of result and see the difference.

Comment: i try getSQL() like you said, and effectively I've "?" and not 20 in parameter.

Comment: Then you have your error - check what changes its value from 20 to 2 and you'll be good.

Comment: No I'm a dumb, it's okay, just I put the var_dump after the foreach, so I've seen only the last result, who is truely set to 2. Sorry... But I've again "?" in place of a true parameter. I edit my post to show you.

Comment: @JulienLeray "?" is the placeholder value that doctrine will handle, it's normal

Comment: Same think when I simplify the query by: $v = $this->_em->createQuery('select v from Btp\UserProBundle\Entity\Ville v
       where v.rayon = :ray')
                ->setParameter('ray', 20) //20
                ->getSQL();

Comment: @JulienLeray if you want to get the query without ? for debugging, then use: `$v = $this->_em->createQuery('select v from Btp\UserProBundle\Entity\Ville v where v.rayon = 20')`

Comment: Click on db queries (all the over to the right on the symfony debug toolbar).  It will show you the sql queries as well as the ? parameter values.

Comment: It's also a little bit puzzling that your posted sql code has four placeholders (i.e. ?) even though you only have three parameters.  Anyways, post the parameters as shown by the debug toolbar.

Comment: I think It's normal to have four parameter, I use GEO() function, and it replace GEO by all cumputing who need two times the same variable. Maybe I'm wrong be this think don't choc me...

Comment: try convert $value->getRayon() into integer: ->setParameter('r', intval($value->getRayon()))

Comment: @repincln already tried, nothing change... i also try to cast directly (int), do not work...

Comment: what about: ...WHERE GEO(v.lat = :latitude, v.lng = :longitude) <= ?1 ... ->setParameter(1, $value->getRayon());

Comment: Typically this would mean that your query is returning the expected results but you have some other problem in your code.  The posted code does not show what you do with $v.  Take a break then take a fresh look at what you do with $v.

Comment: @repincln I'an error, I don't know this syntax, are you sure about your line?

Comment: @Cerad I just do var_dump($v); exit;, I doen't make anything special; and I've nothing in the array, but it's work when an number like 20 is hardcoded...

Comment: Take a look at 13.2.1. - http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: @repincln i just tried, this doesn't change nothing... Just for your information, you can't mix :val and ?1 in same request. thank you anyway

Comment: Does it work if you before query write $x = 20 and then use $x at your parameters? Is this work? What if you put $x = "20" (in quotes)?

Comment: This two way work. it's strange this is work with quote no? the query wait for an integer so...

Comment: 4 hours on this bug!!! It's make me crazy... Any other ideas are welcome...

Comment: There must be something with query $villes. Can you post action method and entity Ville?

Comment: What type of database are you using?  I have a suspicion that maybe it not mysql?  GEO returns an integer?

Comment: Okay, after a day of search, i find solution,... I think problem come from session/cookies data; because I 'd change type of rayon as VARCHAR to INT for my migration. After clear the cache, delete cookies and session, this work fine. Thanks to all, If you want to answer I give you vote and validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this strange behaviour come from cache/cookie. Previously I made migration from database who have change the field rayon varchar to int. So fter clear the cache, all works properly.

Sorry for disturbing you for so dumb answer.

Thanks to all!